# How to: Set Firebase user's profile info on signup/creation? (Flutter-web)

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, flutter-web

How can I set a user's displyName at the same time as creating their account?

I'm using the createUserWithEmailAndPassword method and trying to take the information from 3 different TextFormFields within the same Form.

Below is a very simple example of what I'm trying to do... Hopefully from this someone will be able to help..

Thanks

This is my signup method:

```
import 'package:firebase_auth/firebase_auth.dart';

class AuthService {
  FirebaseAuth auth = FirebaseAuth.instance;

  //Create user with email and password (+ displayName)
  signUp({String email, String password, String name}) async {
    await FirebaseAuth.instance
        .createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email: email, password: password);


        // I'd like to create/update the new user's displayName here, using the String value (name) being passed into this function.



  }
}
```

This is an example of where the data is coming from:

```
class SignUpForm extends StatelessWidget {
  final GlobalKey<FormState> _formKey = GlobalKey();

  String name;
  String email;
  String password;

  TextEditingController nameController;
  TextEditingController emailController;
  TextEditingController passwordController;

  submit(){
    AuthService().signUp(password: 'password', email: email, name: name);
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Form(
      key: _formKey,
      child: Column(
        children: <Widget>[
          TextFormField(
            controller: nameController,
            onChanged: (value) {
              name = value;
            },
          ),
          TextFormField(
            controller: emailController,
            onChanged: (value) {
              email = value;
            },
          ),
          TextFormField(
            controller: passwordController,
            onChanged: (value) {
              password = value;
            },
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The user object is returned from the createUserWithEmailAndPassword function's promise and you can then update the displayName immediately after by issuing a further request to firebase.

```
 await FirebaseAuth.instance.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email: email, password: password)
          .then((user){
    var userUpdateInfo = new UserUpdateInfo(); //create user update object
    userUpdateInfo.displayName = "John Doe"
    await firebaseAuth.updateProfile(userUpdateInfo); //update to firebase
    await user.reload(); //reload  user data
})
```

More info about UserUpdateInfo class here:
https://pub.dev/documentation/firebase_auth/latest/firebase_auth/UserUpdateInfo-class.html

You may also want to check out the example app on the firebase github repository. I've linked to the file and line which is relevant to what you are seeking to achieve:

https://github.com/FirebaseExtended/flutterfire/blob/7ccdd3b9bca948d15b397fe5c86ec4616b611c47/packages/firebase_auth/firebase_auth/example/lib/register_page.dart#L88

EDIT

Final working code:

```
class AuthService {
FirebaseAuth auth = FirebaseAuth.instance;

signUp({String email, String password, String name}) async {
await FirebaseAuth.instance
.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email: email, password: password)
.then(
(value) async {
var userUpdateInfo = new UserUpdateInfo(); //create user update object
userUpdateInfo.displayName = "John Doe";
await value.user.updateProfile(userUpdateInfo); //update to firebase
await value.user.reload();

print('displayname= ${userUpdateInfo.displayName}');
},
);
}
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I'll give this a try!

Comment: You're welcome. Although bear in mind, if you creating an account using only email and password then the displayName will not have yet been saved to Firebase. If you were using Google Signup, on the other hand, this info would be available, as Google already hold it.

Comment: Perhaps you could ellaborate further about how your app works; what data do you collect from the user; maybe, share some of your code. This would help alot. I see someone has down voted your question. I think this is a little unfair as you a new member. If you add some code excerpts and a litte more info about what you are trying to achieve, the question might get some up votes.

Comment: Hi, I'm simply trying to create/update the user's ```displayName``` at the same time as creating a Firebase user with Email and Password... I will update my question with some code.

Comment: ok, thanks for the clarification. In that case, you need to send a second request to firebase as soon as your receive the User object. The second request will carry out the update to displayName immiately after the user is created. I'll update my answer for you.

Comment: Thanks, that sounds right to me... I've updated my question with some simple code showing what I'm doing

Comment: I've updated my answer to reflect your clarifications. You should now be able to save a display name immediately after the user creation has resolved.

Comment: Hi mate, thanks so much for your help... Would you be able to show a working example based on the method I have in my question? I think it might be working, but I've been trying to print the displayName to the console at the end of the function and it's showing null still... Not sure if that's because the print isn't waiting before firing

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/208262/discussion-between-matwr-and-chris).

Answer (score 0):

```
_createUser() async {
await _auth
    .createUserWithEmailAndPassword(
  email: emailText,
  password: passwordText,
)
FirebaseUser user = await _auth.currentUser();

  UserUpdateInfo updateInfo = UserUpdateInfo();
  updateInfo.displayName = 'John Doe';
  await user.updateProfile(updateInfo);
  print('USERNAME IS: ${user.displayName}');
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I'll give this a try!

Comment: Hi mate, I tried this (even with hard-coding the displayName and I'm still getting "USERNAME IS: null"

Comment: sorry try adding await before updateProfile I will update the answer

Comment: Hi mate, is it working for you? I'm still getting "null"